# Webform and TypeForm

Tags: webforms

How would I add an image to a Drupal Webform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to including anything in a Webform is to use the "Advanced HTML/Text" element, which allows you to utilize Drupal's Text Format functionality to embed any media, including videos.

Comment: thanks for pointing this direction. Could this (w/ css, I suppose) would make the form over the graphic (jpg or video) ?

Comment: Yes, as an administrator, you can inject custom CSS and JS into a webform.

Comment: Thanks @ jrockowitz